# Who pays for plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

Do I pay if a plumber did more than asked for on a job? Asked to replace a hot water shut off valve **handle**. He removed both shut off valves and replaced them.

Comment: You pay the plumber. If you think work was done that was not contracted, feel free to ask why and go from there. Chances are, the work was needed and you should be grateful? one was bad, why would the other not be close behind? You can probably fight it but something tells me the price,or the way work was requested is not worth the dispute

Comment: How much was the quote to fix the one valve?  How much did plumber add fir replacing the second?

Comment: He did you a favor.   He saved you from calling him back when the cold valve fails.

Comment: The reason for replacing handle can be important.  A broken handle because of bad valve/s or you just wanted another handle for looks.

Comment: There's no throne.  The incremental cost to replace the second valve was trivial compared to the costs of getting the plumber out there in the first place (this cost is called "mobilization").  Even if you won the argument perfectly you'd only cut the bill by 10% at most.  And then you'd just have to pay that 90% cost a second time when the second valve fails.

Answer (score 6):

In general, a broken handle on a shut-off valve is a STRONG indicator that the valve needs to be replaced - otherwise the original handle would not have broken. Replacing a handle on a valve that requires so much force to operate that the handle breaks is *not good workmanship*, and does not *solve the problem* of an inoperable shutoff.

If the one was bad (sounds like a fixture hot - cold pair, but you didn't say) it's commonly the case that the other one is as well.

So, you pay the plumber. You might ask questions, but you pay the plumber.

If you are upset about a fairly normal "you see this problem (a handle) the plumber sees that problem (a pair of valves that are failing or failed)" then be immediately available when the plumber is working to discuss changes in scope and why they are being changed. And be very clear that you want to discuss any changes in scope beforehand.

This time, you pay the plumber.

Comment: One of my favorite parts of being a handyman is loading the truck with stuff that I don't need because **clients have no idea what the objective should be based off of their own complaint**. If I had a dollar for every time I went back out to the truck for *'something I didn't need'*, I wouldn't have to work anymore.